# Unknown white precipitate in electrolysis of water

Tags: electrochemistry

I was electrolysing water using a copper anode and zinc cathode.  The water was from the tap and where I live is very hard.  I was using about 20V between the two electrodes.  As I applied the voltage, a white precipitate formed around the anode.  What is strange is that I can't replicate this using any other type of metal as the anode.  Any ideas on what this might be? [image]  Or, I suppose a better question is: are there any ideas on how I can find out what this was?

Comment: What other anode materials have you tried?

Comment: I've tried iron, aluminum, and graphite.

Comment: The aluminum probably just [anodized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodizing) and stopped the current flow -- I'm guessing there was no bubbling there?  As for iron, was it actually iron, or was it a steel of some kind?

Comment: Yes, it was steel

Comment: Aha --- stainless steel?

Comment: No, it was from a computer case.  Once I left it for a few days after my electrolysis experiments it most certainly stained :-P It's all rusted now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slight bluish tinge to that white precipitate makes it look to me more like [copper(II) hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_hydroxide) than anything to do with the hardness minerals, especially since you haven't observed it with other anode metals thus far.

One way to test this would be to make a whole bunch of the precipitate, by running the current for a long time, and then taking a small sample of the liquid with precipitate in it and adding an equal volume of distilled vinegar (5% acetic acid).  If it is indeed $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$, I think it should dissolve to form a clear blue solution of [copper(II) acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_acetate).

The only problem might be if 5% acetic acid isn't able drop the pH far enough, in which case you'd have to track down a more concentrated acid. One choice might be $\ce{HCl}$, which is available at, e.g., aquarium supply stores under its historical name of muriatic acid. You'd then get a solution of [copper(II) chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_chloride#Properties_and_reactions), the color of which will vary depending on the $\ce{Cl-}$ concentration. Another option, per MaxW's comment, would be pickling vinegar (10% acetic acid) -- in fact, a quick search just revealed that Amazon has several [vinegar options](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=pickling%20vinegar) available in higher acidities.

Comment: How would I determine if it was produced?  I'm a bit new to electrochemistry but does it have something to do with the overvoltage I used?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky As re overvoltage, not really. Anodic electrolysis of copper in neutral aqueous media is likely to make $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ regardless of the applied potential, as long as it's large enough to get electrons flowing.

Comment: Since the water was noted as hard, I'd guess some sort of copper (II) carbonate would be in the ppt as well. // "Picking vinegar" is 10% acetic acid, as opposed to "regular vinegar" which is 5%.

Comment: @MaxW Agreed, $\ce{CuCO3}$ is certainly possibility, depending on the type of [hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_water) in OP's water. Either way, acidification should solubilize it, I figure?

Answer (score 0):

Metallic copper at the anode works as an electrode producing $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$, the slight blue pricipitate you observed in the course of reaction.  The $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ gradually releases water creating a black precipitate of, CuO. Please read our work in which we described the homemade reactions to synthesized copper(II) aspirinate and acetate:

[[1]](http://www.edu.utsunomiya-u.ac.jp/chem/v11n2/PerezBenitez/PEREZ_BODY.html)
[[2]](http://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV3OOOtN_MAhUBySYKHSqaANgQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.educacionquimica.info%2Fdescargapermitida.php%3FId_articulo%3D1299&usg=AFQjCNFxqhuAgzqqPs-saWHNBkXn2-GfuA&sig2=PwFevl8Kk69T3XozxLwG8A)

Comment: This may be a matter of language but a sacrificial anode is not what copper is  in this case.